# Passing and processing List<> types containing objects of the same base type

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

Consider the following classes:

```
class TypeA;
class TypeB : TypeA;
class TypeC : TypeA;
class TypeD : TypeA;
```

and the following List<> types:

```
List<TypeB> listTypeB;
List<TypeC> listTypeC;
List<TypeD> listTypeD;
```

Now TypeA has a property Prop1 of type Object1 and I want to locate which list has stored within it an item with Prop1 of a given value. Is there a way in which I can do something like the following, so that I only need to write the search code once?

```
bool LocateInAnyList(Object1 findObj)
{
  bool found = false;

  found = ContainsProp1(findObj, listTypeB);
  if(!found)
  {
    found = ContainsProp1(findObj, listTypeC);
  }
  if(!found)
  {
    found = ContainsProp1(findObj, listTypeD);
  }
  return found;
}


bool ContainsProp1(Object1 searchFor, List<TypeA> listToSearch)
{
   bool found = false;

   for(int i = 0; (i < listToSearch.Count) & !found; i++)
   {
      found = listToSearch[i].Prop1 == searchFor;
   }
   return found;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use generic

```
bool ContainsProp1<T>(Object1 searchFor, List<T> listToSearch) where T : TypeA
{
   bool found = false;

   for(int i = 0; (i < listToSearch.Count) & !found; i++)
   {
      found = listToSearch[i].Prop1 == searchFor;
   }
   return found;
}
```

If you can use linq, your code can be more clear than that.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You'll need to make the "contains" method generic, with a constraint so that you can operate only on objects that derive from `TypeA` (and thus have a `Prop1`:)

```
bool ContainsProp1<T>(Object1 searchFor, List<T> listToSearch) where T : TypeA
{
   bool found = false;

   for(int i = 0; (i < listToSearch.Count) & !found; i++)
   {
      found = listToSearch[i].Prop1 == searchFor;
   }
   return found;
}
```

Your first method should then compile as-is.

Comment: Are you sure that compiles like that?

Comment: I removed my extra typoed colon; other than that, yeah, looks fine to me.

Comment: Close - unfortunately ybo syntax was correct for the function definition, but have +1 anyway.

Comment: When I paste that code as is, the IDE highlights the 'where' keyword with the following error:  "Constraints are not allowed on non-generic declarations"

To fix it I had to change it to this:

bool ContainsProp1<T>(Object1 searchFor, List<T> listToSearch) where T : TypeA {...}

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this (using lambdas & generics & nice things like that):

```
public bool LocateInAnyList(Object1 obj)
{
    return SearchList(listTypeB, obj) || SearchList(listTypeC, obj) || SearchList(listTypeD, obj);
}

private static bool SearchList<T>(List<T> list, Object1 obj) where T : TypeA
{
    return list.Exists(item => item.Prop1 == obj);
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd say this should be the accepted answer. It is fairly well documented that these delegate based methods are faster than iterating through the list by hand. Plus it's a lot more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

You won't really be able to do this in this way until C# 4.0 comes out because of the added variance/covariance support.

You can hack it for now by allowing the user to pass in IEnumerable, and just looping over that while casting the object to TypeA

```
bool ContainsProp1(Object1 searchFor, IEnumerable listToSearch)
{
   bool found = false;

   foreach(object obj in listToSearch)
   {
      found = ((TypeA)obj).Prop1 == searchFor;
      if (found) break;
   }
   return found;
}
```

Comment: Covariance is unnecessary for this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. First, you can make the method generic, by changing its signature like the following:

```
bool ContainsProp(Object searchFor, List<T> listToSearch) : where T : TypeA {}
```

this will allow you to pass any of the lists you have.

Second, I would change the second parameter to receive an array of lists:

```
bool ContainsProp<T>(Object searchFor, List<T> [] listsToSearch) where T : TypeA {}
```

This way, you could pass all the lists at once:

```
found = ContainsProp(objToSearch, listA, listB, listC);
```

Comment: have you even checked your examples compile?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't compile because I'm not showing the entire implementation, just the method signature, like I mention in the first line.